# What should I do with corroded heating pipes that were previously under concrete and which I'm about to re-concrete and board over?

Tags: heating, pipe, floor, corrosion

I have two copper pipes that were lagged in fiberglass wool and concreted over and which I'm about to re-lag with a plastic pipe then re-concrete and lay laminate flooring on top. The pipes themselves have a thin layer of green oxidization which I'm thinking of just cleaning off before proceeding with lagging - given they will have no access to oxygen and I'm protecting them from contact with the new concrete I'm thinking this will be fine as the pipes appear solid enough. But I'm no expert :) and hence asking for opinions. These pipes disappear beneath parquet flooring so if replacing would only be able to replace a short run. An alternative could be to place a strips of wood around the lagged pipes and concrete with one above the pipes flush with the concrete it could be prised from the concrete to gain access and replaced the pipes at a future date?

[image: pipes freed from old concrete]

[image: close up of copper pipes]

Comment: Why do you want to re-concrete them? You now know how much of a pain in the arse that will be if repairs are ever needed again... There has to be a better solution.

Comment: What if I use sharp sand just around the pipes and smoothed off to the level required? If that's only a couple or so inches wide I would have thought that would be stable enough to take the laminate boards.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the oxidation.  For most metals, it protects the rest of it from oxidising.